Help With Basic TFL Problem
I am new to formal logic and need help with Chapter 5.3 of ForAllX.
The sentence is "You will have neither soup nor salad."
The textbook symbolizes this as ¬(A V B).
HOW does ¬(A V B) imply that you cannot have A AND you cannot have B?
Shouldn't it be symbolized as (¬A ∧ ¬B) instead?
All help is appreciated. Thanks.

These are equivalent. Do you need help convincing yourself that they should be, or proving that they are using the rules of logic? In natural language it's pretty obvious that "you will not have (soup or salad)" means the same thing as "you will not have soup and you will not have salad".

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

Your two logical expressions are equivalent.
They are an example of De Morgan’s_laws.
The two expressions can be proved equal using a truth table:
$$
  \begin{matrix}
    A & B & \lnot A & \lnot B & A \lor B &
    \lnot (A \lor B) & (\lnot A) \land (\lnot B)\\
  \hline
    F & F & T & T & F & T & T\\
    F & T & T & F & T & F & F\\
    T & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
    T & T & F & F & T & F & F\\
  \end{matrix}
$$
Notice that the first two columns give every possible value of $A$ and $B$.
The last two columns give the truth value of your two expressions.  Notice that in all cases the two values are equal.
